# Running php adword api examples in browser has blank output but in cli it displays output

Tags: google-ads-api

When I run the file **GetKeywordIdeas.php** from the adwords api php library the output in the browser is blank but when running from the command line it displays. Are there any settings I need to change in the wamp server or anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

With a search on the internet you can see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/oMlCjm2_gXw) where it says

> If you are using the AdWords API PHP client library, you have to use the command line. You can instead use the Keyword Planner tool in the AdWords UI where you can search for keyword and ad group ideas. More information about the Keyword Planner is available here. That response is from someone on the google adwords api team.

Answer (score 0):

solve issue
i use exec command to run this file in php.
$arr= exec('GetKeywordIdeas.php');